# Added new user with password, other users without password cannot login anymore

Tags: windows-7, passwords

I added a new non-admin user to a Windows 7 laptop. After reboot the existing users are required to enter their passwords. However, I am told those users never had a password set.

Any advice what might have happened here?

Comment: Describe it a little more(about admin,password).

Answer (score 3):

Having one account requiring a password will trigger the credentials window for everybody, but they can just enter without password. It should just mean that they have an additional click to perform, without entering a password.